# JobDSL custom config file

Tags: jenkins-job-dsl

I'm trying to setup a jenkins job with custom config file, original xml looks as follows (the relevant part):

```
<buildWrappers>
  <org.jenkinsci.plugins.configfiles.buildwrapper.ConfigFileBuildWrapper plugin="config-file-provider@2.11">
    <managedFiles>
      <org.jenkinsci.plugins.configfiles.buildwrapper.ManagedFile>
        <fileId>30de8d2f-621d-4c51-b644-4302b548fd15</fileId>
        <targetLocation>./src/</targetLocation>
        <variable/>
        <replaceTokens>false</replaceTokens>
      </org.jenkinsci.plugins.configfiles.buildwrapper.ManagedFile>
    </managedFiles>
  </org.jenkinsci.plugins.configfiles.buildwrapper.ConfigFileBuildWrapper>
</buildWrappers>
```

Here's my JobDSL attempt:

```
job('example') {
    configure{
    it / 'buildWrappers' << 'org.jenkinsci.plugins.configfiles.buildwrapper.ManagedFile' {
        managedFiles {
            org.jenkinsci.plugins.configfiles.buildwrapper.ManagedFile{
                fileId '30de8d2f-621d-4c51-b644-4302b548fd15'
                targetLocation './/src//'
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

What am I missing? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the built-in DSL: https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/#path/job-wrappers-configFiles

The built-in DSL will also resolve the `fileId` from the file name.

```
job('example') {
  wrappers {
    configFiles {
      file('myCustomConfigFile') {
        targetLocation('src')
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello, I've tried using build-in, but I thought that I need to provide fileId and because of that I've started trying with configure, I'll test and come back to you, thanks!